# Slower execution when using an infinite list

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm beginning to try and get my head round haskell performance, and what makes things fast and slow, and I'm a little confused by this.

I have two implementations of a function that generates a list of primes up to a certain value. The first is straight off the Haskell wiki:

```
primesTo :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
primesTo m = eratos [2..m]  where
   eratos []     = []
   eratos (p:xs) = p : eratos (xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..m])
```

The second is the same, but using an infinite list internally:

```
primes2 :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
primes2 m = takeWhile (<= m) (eratos [2..])  where
   eratos []     = []
   eratos (p:xs) = p : eratos (xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..])
```

In both cases, the minus function is:

```
minus :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of 
           LT -> x : minus  xs  (y:ys)
           EQ ->     minus  xs     ys 
           GT ->     minus (x:xs)  ys
minus  xs _ = xs
```

The latter implementation is significantly (~100x) slower than the former, and I don't get why. I would have thought that haskell's lazy evalutation would make them fairly equivalent under the hood.

This is obviously a reduced test case for the purposes of the question - in real life the optimisation would be no problem (although I don't understand why it is needed), but to me a function that just generates an infinite list of primes is more generically useful than a finite list, but appears slower to work with.

Comment: Note that you can boost the takeWhile out of primes2, and get a try more general primes function. You could look at the generated Core and C to see the differences, but I think that in a nutshell, thinking algorithmically, the difference is that the infinite list version does some "overlapping" work that makes getting the m+1 less work than primesTo twice, for m and then for m+1. But if you don't need that work, better to not do it. So for this algorithm you can save work if you know in advance the max m you will need.

Comment: It would be enlightening as an exercise to find another problem+algorithm with a similar property.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like to me that there's a big difference between

```
(xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..m])  -- primesTo
(xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..])   -- primes2
```

The function `minus` steps through lists pairwise and terminates when one list reaches the end. In the first `minus` expression above, this occurs in no more than `(m-p*p)/p` steps when the latter list is exhausted. In the second one, it will always take steps on the order of `length xs`.

So your infinite lists have disabled at least one meaningful optimization.

Comment: I understand that the latter list terminates the execution of minus, and as p tends towards m, the minus calculation gets shorter. What I'm trying to understand is where and when the lazy evaluation does and doesn't apply with infinite lists - I was expecting in this case that minus would only have been evaluated as much as was required to satisfy the takeWhile (and everything above it) which wouldn't have been very different to the explicitly bounded case.

Comment: `minus` doesn't step through the lists pairwise. Only when the heads are equal does `minus` consume from both lists. So the amount of steps will be closer to `length xs` in both cases.

However, in the first one, you can exhaust the list of primes, avoiding a thunk and the checking of `xs` between the last multiple of `p` and what would be the next.

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that in the second case you need to generate one extra prime. You need to generate the first prime greater than `m` before `takeWhile` knows its time to stop.

Additionally, the `[..m]` bounds on both the list to filter and the lists of multiples help reduce the number of calculations. Whenever one of these lists gets empty `minus` immediately returns via its secons clause while in the infinite case the minus gets stuck in the first case. You can explore this a bit better if you also test the cases where only one of the lists is infinite:

```
--this is also slow
primes3 :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
primes3 m = takeWhile (<= m) (eratos [2..m])  where
   eratos []     = []
   eratos (p:xs) = p : eratos (xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..])

--this fast
primes4 :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
primes4 m = takeWhile (<= m) (eratos [2..])  where
   eratos []     = []
   eratos (p:xs) = p : eratos (xs `minus` [p*p, p*p+p..m])
```